# Pandas - Merge rows on column A, taking first values from each column B, C etc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, with recordings of statistics in multiple columns.
I have a `list` of the column names: `stat_columns = ['Height', 'Speed']`.
I want to combine the data to get one row per `id`.
The data comes sorted with the newest records on the top. I want the most recent data, so I must use the first value of each column, by `id`.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Index  id       Height   Speed
0      100007            8.3
1      100007   54  
2      100007            8.6
3      100007   52  
4      100035   39  
5      100014   44       
6      100035            5.6
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Index  id       Height   Speed
0      100007   54       8.3
1      100014   44      
2      100035   39       5.6
```

I have tried a simple `groupby` myself:

`df_stats = df_path.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).first()`

But this seems to only give me a row with the first statistic found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me your solution working, maybe is necessary replace empty values to `NaN`s:

```
df_stats = df_path.replace('',np.nan).groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
print (df_stats)
       id  Index  Height  Speed
0  100007      0    54.0    8.3
1  100014      5    44.0    NaN
2  100035      4    39.0    5.6
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming! My problem was my values were 'None', and not 'NaN'... it's ok now. Thanks

Comment: @BenKailon - It should also working, but if `None` strings is necessary replace to NaN or None type by `replace('None', None)` or `replace('None', np.nan)`